# Three.js Placing image in front of the camera

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to make a flight simulator for a project, and I'm trying to place a cockpit image in front of my camera, which is being controlled with FirstPersonControls, I've tried many things but I can't make it work.

here's what I got so far: [image: The cockpit image should be in front of the camera]

I got this running in a: [Codepen Project](https://codepen.io/rodolfo_rodriguez/pen/RyvMBZ)

This is where I'm trying to place the image.

```
    function onTextureLoad(texture) {
    console.log(texture);
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2, 0);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
     map: texture, transparent: true, opacity: 1 
    });

    var geometryco = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100,100,100,100);
    var cockpit = new THREE.Mesh(geometryco, material);
    cockpit.position.set(0,20,0);

    scene.add(cockpit);

    render();
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @Rabbid76 How would I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Make it a child of the camera so that they move together.

```
camera.add( cockpit )
scene.add( camera )
```

Comment: Where would I place that? , inside the function? , sorry I'm really new at this, I tried that but it doesn't show the image

Comment: Instead of `scene.add( cockpit )`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to put the cockpit in the `img` tag, which is in front of the renderer's canvas:

html:

```
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/VfF0ada.png" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%"/>
```

js:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

https://codepen.io/prisoner849/pen/qYgKvz?editors=0010

Comment: Wait that's css,I just realized.. I need it in three js

Comment: @RodolfoR :) It's up to you. If you want to make it more complicated, so be it.